# How to JUnit MapperToJsonString class

Tags: spring-boot, junit

Please help me concerning my problem on how to unit test my class.

Here is the class that I can't fully cover with my JUnit.

```
@Component
public class Utils {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Autowired
    private LoggingService loggingService;

    public <E> String mapToJsonString(E object) {
        try {
            if (object == null) {
                throw new IOException(ErrorMessage.ERROR_PROCESSING_JSON_NULL);
            }

            return mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT).writeValueAsString(object);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            loggingService.logError(this.getClass().getName(), "1", ErrorMessage.ERROR_MAPPING_TO_JSONSTRING, e);
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my test case:

```
@MockBean
private LoggingService loggingService;
@Before
public void setUp() {
    myModelClass = new MyModelclass();
    myModelClass.setStatus("U");
    myModelClass.setTermCode("001");
    myModelClass.setLocation("BGC");
}

@Test
public void testObjectToJson() throws JsonProcessingException {

    Mockito.when(utils.mapToJsonString(myModelClass)).thenReturn("");
    String output = utils.mapToJsonString(myModelClass);
    assertThat(output).isEqualTo(utils.mapToJsonString(""));
}

@Test(expected=IOException.class)
public void testJsonParsingException() {
    utils.mapToJsonString(null); 
    String output = utils.mapToJsonString(myModelClass);
    Mockito.when(utils.mapToJsonString(null)).thenThrow(new IOException());
    assertThat(output).isNull();
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be mocking `Utils` object or `mapToJsonString()` method as this is the method which you want to test and you would want to call the real method instead of mocked.

Which means following statements should not be present in your junit.

```
Mockito.when(utils.mapToJsonString(myModelClass)).thenReturn("");
Mockito.when(utils.mapToJsonString(null)).thenThrow(new IOException());
```

At the outset, I can think of following junits but you should think of more scenarios to test and write junits for them.

1. Happy scenario : You pass in a object to `mapToJsonString()` and assert/verify the JSON String it returns.
2. Pass `null` to `mapToJsonString()` and assert/verify empty String. As in the `catch` block you are using an external object `loggingService`, you need to mock `loggingService.logError()` call.

Also, do not write any junit for `@Test(expected=IOException.class)` as it will never be successful because you are not re-throwing `IOException` in catch block.

Comment: Thank @Smile you for your response. But it gives me nullPointerException.  When I debug the test case, the utils is null.  Here is my updated code:

Comment: This passing objects to mapToJsonString()                                                                    `String output = utils.mapToJsonString(myModelClass);` 
`assertEquals(output, utils.mapToJsonString(myModelClass));`

Comment: This is for null                                                                                                                   `myModelClass= new MyModelClass();`
`myModelClass = null;`
`String output = utils.mapToJsonString(atm);`
`Mockito.when(loggingService.logError(this.getClass().getName(), "1", ErrorMessage.ERROR_MAPPING_TO_JSONSTRING, new Exception   ())).thenReturn("");`
`assertThat(output).isNull();`

Comment: It's best to update your question with the code as it is more readable than comments. Also, your use of `@MockBean` suggests you are using Spring runner to run the test case. So, you can `@Autowire` the `utils` variable to assign `Utils` object to it.